# select records with two different values

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Using Oracle SQL, If I have this dataset, how can I select only those records which has value of both Europe and America? In other words I don't wanna see Johnny Bravo on the report.

| Name | Surname | Continent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Johnny | Bravo | America |
| Pier | Ruso | Europe |
| Pier | Ruso | America |

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option; it expects that there are two distinct continents per name, where one of them is America and another Europe.

Johnny isn't returned as he has only one continent (America), and Mike isn't in result set as he has 3 continents (two of them *are* America and Europe, but - there are 3 continents in a table for that person):

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (name, surname, continent) as
  2    (select 'Johnny', 'Bravo', 'America' from dual union all
  3     --
  4     select 'Pier'  , 'Ruso' , 'Europe'  from dual union all
  5     select 'Pier'  , 'Ruso' , 'America' from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select 'Mike'  , 'Tiger', 'Europe'  from dual union all
  8     select 'Mike'  , 'Tiger', 'Asia'    from dual union all
  9     select 'Mike'  , 'Tiger', 'America' from dual
 10    )
```

Query:

```
 11  select name, surname
 12  from test
 13  group by name, surname
 14  having count(distinct continent) = 2
 15    and min(continent) = 'America'
 16    and max(continent) = 'Europe';

NAME   SURNAME
------ ----------
Pier   Ruso

SQL>
```

Comment: But then DISTINCT CONTINENTs wouldn't be America and Europe, @jarlh. (Or maybe I didn't understand what you're saying).

Comment: Just forget it. I was wrong,

Comment: @jarlh This is on limitation of the English language; it is ambiguous whether the question is asking for groups that contain "Europe, America and no others" or "Europe, America and any number of others". You are correct that this doesn't work for the latter case; Littlefoot is correct that it does work for the former case. We just don't know which is the OP's requirement (but the linked duplicate covers both cases).

Comment: However, if I want to put more fields in the select, it gives an error:  "not a GROUP BY expression" . Is it possible to slightly enhance the query to be able to list more columns? Grouping is not necessary if it helps.

Comment: You're welcome. If you add other columns into a SELECT column list, you have to include them into the GROUP BY clause as well. I edited code I previously posted which shows *how* so - have a look, please.